# Controlling Powerpoint using Leap motion and Python

Tags: python, cross-platform, powerpoint, desktop-application, leap-motion

I just started up with python.I lately got a project where I have to make a powerpoint slideshow.This has to be done using **leap motion sdk and python**.So my powerpoint will be gesture based.

1. How do I deploy this on my desktop in
   such a away that I just need to click on my desktop app or the ppt file itself, I get
   started with the powerpoint like on windows.
2. I need to detect the finger gestures using python and integrate it
   to **next - previous** functionality.

Can I get some guidance on powerpoint with PPT?

I have got the [API](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/Languages/Python/API/index.html),[Documentation](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/Languages/Python/Guides/Leap_Overview.html),SDK and I am learning [python](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) too.

Comment: Cross-Platform is a bit hard but under windows I would suggest to use the `win32api` to send events to powerpoint once it is started. Would this be an option?

Comment: @User:ok..windows is also ok..

Answer (score 6):

The [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) library has a `win32com.client` module that lets you use [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) API to control PowerPoint.

For example, this code will add a slide with an oval in it:

```
import win32com.client

Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
Presentation = Application.Presentations.Add()
Base = Presentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)
oval = Base.Shapes.AddShape(9, 100, 100, 100, 100)
```

This [IPython notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/sanand0/ipython-notebooks/master/Office.ipynb) has step-by-step examples on how to create a PowerPoint presentation, add objects to it, and make those objects interact in PowerPoint.

While this will allow you to use PowerPoint as an *output interface*, you need a different mechanism for sending messages back from PowerPoint to Python. One way is to set up a Macro that runs on a click event that interacts with [a COM server set up in Python](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html).

Comment: Give him the bounty! The best solution you would get.

Comment: ok,got your point.But the thing is i will get a ready made ppt.So i dont need to append anything to the slides..I need to import the entire ppt and provide a slideshow..Any idea about that?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for this is not fantastic. However, using [win32com](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) and the [PowerPoint API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743835%28v=office.14%29.aspx), you should be able to accomplish what you want to do.

The relevant commands are:

```
import win32com.client
import time

app = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
presentation = app.Presentations.Open(FileName=u'C:\\path\\to\\mypresenation.pptx', ReadOnly=1)

presentation.SlideShowSettings.Run()

time.sleep(1)
presentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next()
time.sleep(1)
presentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next()
time.sleep(1)
presentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Previous()
time.sleep(1)

presentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Exit()

app.Quit()
```

Once you have a reference to the presentation, you can use this inside the code/functions where you handle the gestures.

Comment: i need to import the entire ppt and then control it by gestures..i will figure out the gestures par...

Answer (score 0):

you can some some pointers on what you want to do from this guy https://github.com/sanand0
look at his https://github.com/sanand0/pptx-git repo you should definitely get some pointers.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the Google Slides API. I did some looking around and found this by far the best documentation and easiest setup with regards to python and doing a slide show. Here is a nice quick start guide...

https://developers.google.com/slides/quickstart/python?authuser=1

Answer (score 0):

Use can use win32com

Here is code for slide show run, next, and back slide.

```
import win32com.client
import time
Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
Presentation = Application.Presentations.Open("D:\\dataset\\slide.pptx")
print(Presentation.Name)
Presentation.SlideShowSettings.Run()
time.sleep(3)
Presentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next()
time.sleep(3)
Presentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next()
time.sleep(3)
Presentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Previous()
time.sleep(3)
Application.Quit()
```

Reference: https://github.com/tuantdang/SlideControlUsingBioSigal